# Getting a compile error with ntddscsi.h

Tags: c++, cygwin, scsi

I am having a bit of trouble with the following include:
`#include <ntddscsi.h>`
When I compile (using NetBean 7.1 & Cygwin C++ compiler), I am told that I need to define "SCSI_PASS_THROUGH" before I can use it... in ntddscsi.h however, it is defined:

```
typedef struct _SCSI_PASS_THROUGH {
SHORT  Length;
CHAR  ScsiStatus;
CHAR  PathId;
CHAR  TargetId;
CHAR  Lun;
CHAR  CdbLength;
CHAR  SenseInfoLength;
CHAR  DataIn;
LONG  DataTransferLength;
LONG  TimeOutValue;
LONG_PTR DataBufferOffset;
LONG  SenseInfoOffset;
CHAR  Cdb[16];
} SCSI_PASS_THROUGH, *PSCSI_PASS_THROUGH;
```

Anyone have any idea what on earth is going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if you have circular dependencies, or for example LONG_PTR is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Big help! This solved it - there was indeed a circular dependency! Thank you!